# Creating a tab with JavaScript using CSS display function

Tags: javascript, tabs

I can't figure out what is wrong with my javascript. I have been tasked to create tabs using JS and the CSS display function as part of an assignment.

In all the research I have done, using an unsorted list to create a menu has been suggested, so I have done that and created an onclick event to trigger a function that supposedly would show the content of that tab. But it doesn't - all it shows in the browser is the four bullets and the corresponding text. This I can click on, but the function seems to be broken?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li><a id="tab1" href="/" tabindex="1" onclick="visPanel(1);return false;">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab2" href="/" tabindex="2" onclick="visPanel(2);return false;">Occupations</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab3" href="/" tabindex="3" onclick="visPanel(3);return false;">Education</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab4" href="/" tabindex="4" onclick="visPanel(4);return false;">Epilogue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel">
        <h2><u>Education:</u></h2>
        <p>
        None. Whatsoever.
        </p>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function resetDisplay(){
for (i=1;i<6;i++){
    document.getElementById('panel' + i).style.display="none";
    }
}

function init(){
resetDisplay();
document.getElementById('panel1').style.display="block";
}

function visPanel(nr) {
resetDisplay();
panel=document.getElementById('panel'+nr).style;
panel.display="block";
}

onload=init;
```

As I am quite the novice any pointers to what I have done wrong will be much appreciated!

Comment: You have panel1 but where are the others? `resetDisplay()` has a loop for 5 panels, and your list only has 4 items

Comment: I only included a sample of the body - I should probably have made that more clear from the get-go. 
I changed the for-loop, though, and it works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: ha ok great. For future reference, you can check the console where you're running js. It would have reported the error of undefined element in that loop

Comment: Your variables `i` and `panel` should be declared with `var` in the functions they're used in.